# SetWindowText for combobox

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, combobox, mfc

I want to set the text of combobox that is not present in the combobox list.
For example if the combobox has 3 items:

1. apple
2. orange
3. banana

I am doing this selection change event of combobox.

```
ON_CBN_SELCHANGE(IDC_COMBO, OnComboClick)

void CmmAcceptCtrl::OnComboClick()
{
    CString str;
    m_combo.GetLBText(m_combo.GetCurSel(), str);

    str += " Test";    

    m_combo.SetWindowText(str);
}
```

Now if I select "orange" I expect the text of the combobox to become "orange Test" but the text is not changed, I get "orange" in spite of the fact that I'm doing a `SetWindowText`.

Is there a way we can have a different text from the one that has been selected from the combobox list?

Comment: The dropdown style matters, CBS_DROPDOWNLIST won't permit a mismatch.

Comment: @HansPassant actually none of the combobox styles permits a mismatch.

Comment: why don't you just change the item itself? you can keep a separated data structure that contains the original names if you need to, so you can refill the combobox with the original names and modify the selected one

Comment: We don't know what this control really is since you didn't tell us the style

Comment: @MichaelWalz The other two styles allow arbitrary text to be typed in the edit control, it doesn't have to match an entry in the list.

Comment: Its a CBS_DROPDOWN style. So what I can conclude is that we cannot have the mismatch right?

Comment: Aren't you missing an UpdateData(); call at the end?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but I came here with the same question and then found a trick...

In the ON_CBN_SELCHANGE handler, you can post yourself a message with say

```
PostMessage( WM_COMMAND, ID_AddTestToMyComboText)
```

and use SetWindowText in the handler for that.